# How to create a dict with letters as keys and values as ascii value? i don't want to do it letter by letter tho

Tags: python, dictionary

i have made this code but i am getting the opposite.

```
asciidict = dict()
alfapetTeller = range(97,123)
for i in alfapetTeller:
    asciidict[str(i)] = chr(i)
print(asciidict)
```

Comment: Have you considered just using the `ord` function whose purpose is to take a character and give you the relevant code?

Comment: What Jon said. Why do you think you need this dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the assignment line to:

```
asciidict[chr(i)] = i
```

will do the trick. However, note that there are utils in Python to simplify this task:

```
>>> import string
>>> d = {c: ord(c) for c in string.ascii_lowercase}  # doesn't require you to know the range
>>> d
{'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99, 'd': 100, 'e': 101, 'f': 102, 'g': 103, 'h': 104, 'i': 105, 'j': 106, 'k': 107, 'l': 108, 'm': 109, 'n': 110, 'o': 111, 'p': 112, 'q': 113, 'r': 114, 's': 115, 't': 116, 'u': 117, 'v': 118, 'w': 119, 'x': 120, 'y': 121, 'z': 122}
```

See the docs on [string module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string), [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr).

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. what method can i use to print it backwards?

Comment: Print what backwards? The key, value pairs?

Comment: the whole dict actually. but i found this code to do the job
print('{' + ','.join(str(asciidict)[1:-1].split(',')[::-1]) + '}')

Comment: That is very hacky and relies on the dict having an order which it doesn't (if not by accident)! It is better use an `OrderedDict` or sort the keys manually...

Answer (score 0):

Then you just do the opposite.

```
asciidict[chr(i)] = i
```

Or if you want ascii values as strings.

```
asciidict[chr(i)] = str(i)
```